# random заполняет две матрицы одинаковыми значениями

Tags: c#, .net

Рандом работает не так как нужно: при каждом вызове функции Random, матрицы заполняются одинаково

```
public void Random()
{
    Random random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            matrix[i, j] = random.Next(0, 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/767999

Comment: @PetSerAl Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[По умолчанию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/h343ddh9(v=vs.110).aspx), `Random` использует текущее время, в качестве начального значения в генераторе псевдослучайных чисел. Раз у Вас обе матрицы одинаковые, значит вызовы `Random()` функции происходят слишком близко по времени. В качестве решения, Вы можете использовать один объект класса `Random` в обоих вызовах, чтобы исключить подобную ситуацию; т.е. Вам нужно вынести `Random` в поле класса.

Comment: ... а ещё лучше, завести отдельный экземпляр для всего приложения (если оно однопоточное).

Comment: @VladD, не соглашусь. С глобальными объектами больше головной боли, чем они решают. Если у автора есть класс, который отвечает за создание псевдослучайных матриц, то ему достаточно иметь поле `Radom`, если это будет нужно в других классах — пусть там будет свой `Random`

Comment: Ну, от глобального рандома я проблем не вижу. А вот если у ТС, например, один класс выдаёт случайные X-координаты, а другой — случайные Y-координаты, и у каждого свой Random, то может случайно оказаться, что всегда X = Y. (Или один класс выдаёт координаты охотников, а другой — зайцев.) Поэтому я за глобальный Random.

Comment: В .NET Core данной проблемы нет, `Random()` берёт случайный seed, не привязанный ко времени.

Answer (score -1):

Как уже упоминалось выше вынесите из метода создание экзмепляра `Random`, правда это не всегда помогает. Придется добавить в цикл сохранение предыдущего результата генерации, а саму генерацию в цикле:

```
do { 
    генерить newNumber
} while(oldNumber == newNumber)
```

Comment: Не нужно так делать. Два одинаковых числа подряд - это нормально. А вот подобные проверки как раз искажают распределение.